# How to use plotroc if TPR and FPR is given

Tags: matlab, plot, roc

I try to draw a nice ROC plot in matlab but I don't know how to use function. Can anybody help me with the input- parameters? I have determined TP, FP, TN, FN --> TPR and FPR are known. I don't get it how I can use the function [plotroc](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/nnet/ref/plotroc.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `plotroc` function calculates the TPR and FPR for you, so you have to feed it with your raw data (`targets`, `outputs`) that you used to determine the TP, FP, TN and FN initially.

If you already have the TPR and FPR, use a [classical 2-D line plot](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) such as `plot(FPR, TPR)`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So Targets indicates what for the classification was expected (1 member of class 0 not member of class) and outputs what was classified (again >0.5 member of class < not member). Is this correct?

Comment: @xandi1987: sounds about right, the exact specifications are given in http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/nnet/ref/roc.html